# gRPC Error with tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-estimator

I'm running TensorFlow `1.4` installed via `pip` on Ubuntu 16.04 running on OpenStack. I followed the TensorFlow linear model tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) to run a simple logistic regression model. Everything works fine running locally. I'm following the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) on `RunConfig()`to run the model on a small cluster. As far as I understand things, distributing the canned estimators is only a matter of setting up the appropriate JSON environment variable. I have done this as follows:

```
rank = int(argv[1])
instance_type = argv[2]
...
cluster = {'chief': ['master:2222'],
           'ps': ['master:2223'],
           'worker' : ['worker-1:2222']}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG']= json.dumps(
    {'cluster': cluster,
    'task': {'type': instance_type, 'index': rank}})
...
indep_vars = build_vars()
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig()
lr = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(model_dir=None,
                                   config = config,
                                   feature_columns=indep_vars)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn_logit(data_path, 1, BATCH_SIZE),
    max_steps=10)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn_logit(data_path, 1, BATCH_SIZE),
    steps=1)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(lr, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

I then invoke the script from `master` as: `python tf_dist_example.py 0 chief` and in another window: `python tf_dist_example.py 0 ps` and on `worker-1` as: `python tf_dist_example.py 0 worker`.

The `chief` instance throws an error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Could not start gRPC server` and after setting `export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG`, `gRPC` reports an error:

```
 {"created":"@1513990687.907885617","description":"No address added out of total 1 resolved","file":"external/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.c","file_line":245,"referenced_errors":
[{"created":"@1513990687.907882392","description":"Failed to add any wildcard listeners","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_posix.c","file_line":338,"referenced_errors":
    [{"created":"@1513990687.907869775","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":7,"file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":200,"referenced_errors":
        [{"created":"@1513990687.907859814","description":"OS Error","errno":98,"file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":173,"os_error":"Address already in use","syscall":"bind"}]},
        {"created":"@1513990687.907881598","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":7,"file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":200,"referenced_errors":
            [{"created":"@1513990687.907879042","description":"OS Error","errno":98,"file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":173,"os_error":"Address already in use","syscall":"bind"}]}]}]}
```

The error seems pretty clear: the port on which gRPC is trying to connect is already in use. However, I verified using `netstat -tulpn` that no other process is using any of those ports, so I don't understand why gRPC is complaining that they are already in use. Additionally, if I create a more low level example that creates a `ClusterSpec` and `Server` by hand then the master and worker can communicate fine and everything works as expected. Can anyone offer any suggestions about how to debug further or point out where I'm going wrong? I'm sure there's a simple explanation for what's going on. I can include more messages from `gRPC` if it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this problem and finds this question because they are also using grpc, when I encountered this, the issue was due to an application that listened on both a grpc port and an http port.

I accidentally misconfigured the http port to be the grpc port and thus the application was trying to use the same port twice.